FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field
Using Django 4.2.5, Django-cms 4.1.2, python3.11
I was in the process of trying to enter the content for a static_alias field when I got this error:
Internal Server Error: /en/admin/djangocms_alias/alias/1/change/

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'username' for 
BigAutoField or join on the field not permitted.

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. 
Choices are: created_usergroups, created_users, djangocms_usersettings, email, 
filer_clipboards, filer_folder_permissions, filer_owned_folders, first_name, 
globalpagepermission, groups, id, is_admin, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, 
last_name, locking_users, logentry, owned_files, pagepermission, pageuser, 
password, statetracking, student, teacher, user_permissions, version

I am using an abstract user model:
Models.py
class UserProfile(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(_('Password'), max_length=255)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Is Admin')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Is Staff')
    first_name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=255, verbose_name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=255, verbose_name='Last Name')
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='superuser')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('User Profile')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

Managers.py
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
"""
Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
for authentication instead of usernames.
"""
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given email, and password.
        """
        if not email:
             raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

forms.py
class UserProfileForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'email', 'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'user-email', 'placeholder': 'Email', 'data-validetta': 'required,email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'password', 'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'user-password1', 'placeholder': 'Password', 'data-validetta': 'required,minLength[4],maxLength[20]'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'password', 'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'user-password2', 'placeholder': 'Confirm Password', 'data-validetta': 'required,minLength[4],maxLength[20],equalTo[password1]'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'user-first_name', 'placeholder': 'First Name', 'data-validetta': 'required'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'name': 'user-last_name', 'placeholder': 'Last Name', 'data-validetta': 'required'}))


    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name')

Here's the full traceback:
Internal Server Error: /en/admin/djangocms_alias/alias/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1846, in transform
return self.try_transform(wrapped, name)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1356, in try_transform
raise FieldError(
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'username' for BigAutoField or join on the field not permitted.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
           
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 688, in wrapper
return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 242, in inner
return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1926, in changelist_view
cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\cms\admin\utils.py", line 411, in get_changelist_instance
return super().get_changelist_instance(request)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 836, in get_changelist_instance
return ChangeList(
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 77, in __init__
self.root_queryset = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\djangocms_versioning\admin.py", line 287, in get_queryset
content_created_by=Subquery(versions.values(f"created_by__{conf.USERNAME_FIELD}")[:1]),
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1313, in values
clone = self._values(*fields, **expressions)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1308, in _values
clone.query.set_values(fields)
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 2460, in set_values
self.add_fields(field_names, True)
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 2170, in add_fields
cols.append(join_info.transform_function(target, final_alias))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1850, in transform
raise last_field_exception
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1823, in setup_joins
path, final_field, targets, rest = self.names_to_path(
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\warre\ssenv\ssenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1724, in names_to_path
raise FieldError(
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: created_usergroups, 
created_users, djangocms_usersettings, email, filer_clipboards, 
filer_folder_permissions, filer_owned_folders, first_name, 
globalpagepermission, groups, id, is_admin, is_staff, 
is_superuser, last_login, last_name, locking_users, logentry, 
owned_files, pagepermission, pageuser, password, statetracking, 
student, teacher, user_permissions, version


did you change AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings?

No, it remains:  AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'

This was resolved by adding the following line to settings.py because I am using a custom user model with only e-mail, no username:
DJANGOCMS_VERSIONING_USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

To track the problem, I went into the following files:
site-packages\djangocms_versioning\admin.py
and
site-packages\djangocms_versioning\conf.py

and you just have to use the traceback to find the line that caused the problem.
